# Unity GetComponent<>().GetObject returns false with Equals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class `ProtagonistActor`. Inside I have a public getter `GetActorState`.

In a different class `InputManager` I have:

```cs
ProtagonistActor _protagonistActor;
ActorState _actorState;

private void Awake()
{
    _protagonistActor = GetComponent<ProtagonistActor>();
    _actorState = _protagonistActor._actorState;
}

void OnJumpEvent()
{
    Debug.Log($"Comparingggggggggg {_protagonistActor._actorState.Equals(_actorState)} {_protagonistActor._actorState == _actorState}");
}
```

I was expecting the log to print **True** but it is printing **False** for both.

How is this possible?

Does `GetComponent<ProtagonistActor>().GetSome...` getter returns a new reference?

I event printed out hashcode, they show different values, how?

```
Comparingggggggggg False False 1301530776 -256054432
```

Detailed code example:

```
[Serializable]
public class ActorState
{
    public int tempP;
}

public class ProtagonistActor: MonoBehaviour // Attached to gameobject
{
    [SerializeField] 
    public ActorState _actorState;

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitiateActorState();
    }

    void InitiateActorState()
    {
        _actorState = new ActorState();
    }
}

public class Test2: MonoBehaviour //Attached to Gameobject Player
{
    private ProtagonistActor _protagonistActor;
    private ActorState _actorState;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _protagonistActor = GetComponent<ProtagonistActor>();
        _protagonistActor._actorState.tempP = 90;
        _actorState = _protagonistActor._actorState;
    }

    void OnMyJump()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Comparingggggggggg {_protagonistActor._actorState.tempP} {_actorState.tempP} {_protagonistActor._actorState.Equals(_actorState)} {_protagonistActor._actorState == _actorState} {_protagonistActor._actorState.GetHashCode()} {_actorState.GetHashCode()}");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Comparingggggggggg 0 90 False False 744599944 781808744
```

Comment: The _actorState never changed inside your protagonist actor class? You cache its value once, all changes after that will be ignored. Also, what type is your ActorState?

Comment: Hi I have given a detailed code example, as there `tempP` is only changed inside test2 and changes are reflected in both objects

Comment: Yeah Morion, actorstate was initiated in ProtagonistActor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the call order of your methods. You can make this with the simple `Debug.Log` inside each method.

It seems that `Awake` method of your test is calling earlier than `Awake` of your `ProtagonistActor` class. In this case, you will have logic like:

- `Awake` in the test, cache value to `_actorState`, change parameter inside `_actorState`
- `Awake` in the `ProtagonistActor` class, calling `InitiateActorState` method and creating a **completely new instance** of `ActorState` class with default 0 value.